# Asterisk ivr audio not playing for couple of seconds

Tags: asterisk, audio

I have a arm machine with asterisk 1.8 and free pbx 2.10 gui.
I have an ivrsetup for incoming calls and sometimes the audio of the recording works great. At times though **I can't hear anything for 5-10 seconds and than it just jumps in the middle of the recording**. The recording file used to be a wavfile but since my upload speed isn't that great I converted it (sox) to a **gsm file.**
In the CLI I can see that the **file is being played** so it's not a matter of ownership and the fact that sometimes audio is being played correctly indicates that the file should be OK.
What do you guys think the problem is?

Comment: Please refrain from using ALL CAPS in the future. It's superfluous, since the title is already drawn in **bold** and with a larger font size.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you 1) describe what you use as call source,what technology you use 2) check if you have record,playback, or i/o latency error. For example put your file into tmpfs filesystem

Arm machines are not supported by asterisk team in general and it is expert-grade work setup it on ARM.